# Setting Listview's Item Height not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am facing problem in setting the height of my list  view's item. Below is what I am having in my layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="48dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"            
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="36dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"    
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that some of the text is going out of the list item's height. Can you please help me what I need to do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/> `and check again.

Comment: Removing android:minHeight is not solving the problem.

Comment: Post your XML file where you create ListView

Comment: Post your adapter code,pls.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this attribute `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` from the TextView component.

Comment: Removing android:minHeight is not solving the problem.

Comment: Increase the layout height to 90dp.
i.e change the attribute value to `android:minHeight="90dp"` in your RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use below layout for you listitem,

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="10dp"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/imge"

    />   

   <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

 >       
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textIde"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
   />

      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```